# How to get the smaller tabs back in Safari 6?

Tags: macos, safari

In Safari 6, tabs became very wide. I don’t like this new behavior.

[image: screenshot]

Is there a way to get the old, smaller tabs back?

Comment: Welcome to America - the land of wide. ;-)

Comment: dirty solution.....open a lot of empty tabs....thats what i do

Comment: Oh yeah, I like the new design but it's *only good for touch devices* because the area to switch tabs is a lot bigger in most cases - people with big fingers would enjoy that in iOS. But in OSX this is annoying. We now have to *move the mouse cursor much further*...

Answer (score 2):

The [glims tool - available from Mac update](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/27708/glims) - should do the trick to re-slice the tab width to something fixed if you prefer the old look.

Answer (score 1):

If you have SIMBL installed, download [cosyTabs](https://github.com/inket/cosyTabs) (Lion & Mountain Lion) and your old-style tabs will be back. ([Here's](http://d.pr/gITT)a direct-download link.)

Open the zip and place the .bundle file in: `/Library/Application Support/SIMBL/Plugins/`

Works for me and SIMBL never gave me any trouble. On the website it says that it's only for Mountain Lion, but it works on my Lion Mac as well.

([source](http://macthemes.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&p=858202))